# OSX M1 Ruby 3.1 NotImplementedError: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine

Tags: ruby, apple-m1

Smallest replication available: (note the ruby 3.1.2 / 3.0 difference, but this is a fresh rvm reinstall of ruby 3.1.2 on a system with no other installed rubies (I rvm uninstalled 3.0)

```
# irb
3.1.2 :001 > Kernel.fork
(irb):1:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
from (irb):1:in `<main>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/irb:25:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

First encountered after upgrading ruby and switching from cuprite to selenium:

```
NotImplementedError:
fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/childprocess-4.1.0/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:20:in `fork'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/childprocess-4.1.0/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:20:in `launch_process'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/childprocess-4.1.0/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:81:in `start'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:109:in `start_process'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:56:in `block in start'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:54:in `start'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:84:in `launch'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:341:in `service_url'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:321:in `create_bridge'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:89:in `for'
      # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:83:in `browser'
      # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Use Ruby 3.2.0-preview2 on Apple Silicon with Monterey or Ventura

As of this writing, there are currently a number of open issues on the Ruby issue tracker related to various compilation errors on Apple Silicon. While specific issues may have work-arounds, the "big hammer" right now is to just upgrade to [Ruby 3.2.0 Preview 2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/09/09/ruby-3-2-0-preview2-released/) which appears to meet the [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) in resolving a number of M1/M2 compilation issues.

### VM or Container Alternatives

If you can't or won't upgrade, then you might want to use a non-arm64 VM or a [3.1.2 image from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) that's already compiled. However, the latter will not solve any compilation issues you have with gems built outside the container, assuming the container also has the necessary libraries and build tools. As a result, using a VM or upgrading your Ruby are really your best bets.

### Also Consider RubyNext Gem

You might also consider using [RubyNext](https://github.com/ruby-next/ruby-next) if you need to keep compatibility between older Ruby versions and newer ones. Whether you even need it considering Preview 2 is just a beta of a minor version bump is something you'll have to figure out. Likewise, whether RubyNext refinements or transpilation are better options if you go that route (e.g. backporting or polyfills for older Ruby versions rather than just using 3.2.0-preview2 without any newer features) is something you'll need to evaluate yourself. YMMV.